# iOS10 "wake up" on "older" iPhones

Tags: ios

My iPhone is all of 2 years old, an iPhone 6 (not "s") and as a result it doesn't have the magic Raise to Wake feature. At least so I understand.

As a result getting it on and authenticated takes TWO presses of the button plus one to authenticate my finger.

1. Press home once: Screen lights up and says "press home to unlock"
2. Press home again: Displays passcode or TouchID
3. Touch home button to authenticate

This is one click more than iOs 9. And each and every time I use my phone.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Interesting... because of the massive speed increase from my 5S to 6S, if I ever want to see if I have any notifications on my lock screen, I've had to teach myself to not hit Home with an "authorised finger" or it just skips straight past & into the springboard - very irritating indeed. 3 actions do seem a bit much, but it feels like they're moving in the right direction, for me.

Comment: I also have a 6. All you need to do is press the home button once and don't lift your finger. You don't need to remove it and replace it for TouchID to kick off.

Comment: Interesting @StephenCollins. It works but I have to hold my finger still for what seems like 2 seconds. An eternity.

Comment: @StephenCollins - that's how my 6S currently works, press, release-but-don't-let-go-entirely - Tadahh, springboard. ..but too fast if you want to see notifications.

Comment: By the way whoever down voted it. Why? It was a good question and now we have a valuable answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raise to wake; No.

---

Unlock and go to the home screen with one press; Yes.

1. Settings
2. General
3. Accessibility
4. Home Button
5. Rest Finger to Open

   [image: Image of Rest Finger to Open setting in Public iOS 10 beta 6]

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for finding that. Useful for everyone not just accessibility users!!!

Comment: I'm happy to have been able to help :)